# ActiveXObject Javascript Programming Reference for Excel

Tags: javascript, excel, reference, activexobject

I'm looking for an indepth tutorial for using ActiveXObjects from Javascript. Does anyone know of a reference so I can learn how to program Excel documents using ActiveXObjects?

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bbdkx3k(v=VS.84).aspx)?

Comment: I mean for something Excel specific

Comment: Some instructions in MSDN: [How to automate Excel from an HTML Web page by using JScript](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/234774).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [the Excel object model documenation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee861528.aspx). It might be more .NET-focused than JScript-focused, but it's all based on the same COM objects, so it should still be readily applicable for the most part